# get available memory under SLURM using C++

Tags: c++, hpc, slurm, supercomputers

I'm working in HPC environment and I'm using SLURM to submit my job to the queue. I'm writing my own memory caching mechanism and hence I want to know how much memory is available per node so that I can expand or reuse space.

Is there a way to know how much memory is available.
Does SLURM sets up any  environment variables.

Comment: There is not any environment variable with information about memory. You should use the Slurm API (https://slurm.schedmd.com/api.html) in order to iterate the nodes and check their memory.

Comment: Talking from zero experience with it: there is also a perl API

Answer (score 3):

Several options:

If **cgroups** are setup, you can get that information simply reading file

```
 /cgroup/memory/slurm/uid_<UISERID>/job_<JOBID>/memory.limit_in_bytes
```

on each node.

Otherwise, using the **SLURM API** as @siserte suggested can work.

Or querying the **rlimits** using [getrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) should also work.

Answer (score 1):

In my question I incorrectly stated I want to access memory available per node. My MPI tasks are mapped to 1 cpu, so I actually needed to access memory available per cpu.

If you are submitting job through `sbatch` you can access `--mem-per-cpu` using environment variable `SLURM_MEM_PER_CPU`, documented here: https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html

If memory available in node is required, SLURM api documented at https://slurm.schedmd.com/api.html can be used, as mentioned by @siserte  and @damienfrancois